# Is there a way to redirect or forward just the www traffic from an ubuntu server to my website home page on another domain name?

Tags: 14.04, server, redirect

I have a website hosted on a particular place with a normal www.sitename.com.  I also purchased the .net version of the sitename and want to use it as an sftp only server.  The domain is from Google domains, and the sftp server is at digital ocean. I have the .net resolving and working perfectly with the sftp and it is just what I want, however even though we don't promote or publish the .net name I'm thinking that if I want to do this long term it would be nice if someone accidentally went to www.sitename.net, they would be re-directed to the .com website.  Is this possible, and if so how?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to log into digital ocean .net domain and add the dns entry of the .com in the www field in the dns records.

Comment: Can you add details, or point me to a tutorial?  When you say log in, do you mean ssh to the server or something in the digital ocean control panel?   Thanks in advance.